# As3 Flash trying to hide a clip / frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code:

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:Event){});

login_btn.buttonMode = true; // show hand cursor

//adding event listener
login_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loginUser);

function loginUser(e:MouseEvent):void{
    //if username & password are correct allow entry
    if(IDTxt.text == "wixlab"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    if(IDTxt.text == "hello"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    if(IDTxt.text == "hello"){
        gotoAndStop(2);

    }else {
        //otherwise show an error message
        var alert:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        alert.color = 0xff0000; //red font
        messageTxt.text = "Incorrect ID, Please try again.";
        messageTxt.setTextFormat(alert);
    }
}
```

and in the frame 2, i have stop();

Please i am trying to make it ones they login, the whole clip just go away so they can click on what is behind it. i am using Wix to add this SWF to hide a video. but ones they are logined you won't be able to click on the video because the swf is above it.

please help

Comment: What exactly do you need to hide? A button? A movieClip?

Answer (score 0):

If you move all this code to a layer just for scripting, at frame 1 (which you may already have) you could write a simple conditional that says something like `if (this.currentFrame == 2){ getRidOfMyObjects(); }` I'm not positive that syntax is correct, but you could put this right under your current conditional statement. And `getRidOfMyObjects` could be simple visibility commands or removeChild or whatever is best for your scene...Does this help?

Comment: Thanks lot for your reply! please can you take a look at this file here: (i have uploaded it). http://www.mediafire.com/?wn3ejqne7inkezl

Comment: So basically, this thing will be used to protect videos on a wix.com website. so it will be placed on a top of a video. everything works. apart of. when you actually unlock it. you can't click on the video because technically there is an object above the video which is this too. so i am trying to find out what to do. hide it? transparent? or move it? please pleas help me.

Comment: if you simply dont want to see your object you can use `myObject.visible=false;` ... If you want to leave your object on the stage, but be able to click through it, you can use `myObject.mouseEnabled=false;`